# multiple eqneditor of ckeditor not showing math overlay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using equation editor(for math function) plugin with ck-editor. In a single page where i am using multiple editor. when i am hover on math symbols it showing all function for only one editor but not multiple.

Please help how to show all functions for all editor in a single page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this topic is still open to discussion, but I felt at the same problem this week, and I've developed a solution.

https://github.com/ygorlazaro/eqneditorfix

It's just a .JS file you need to add at your project, and I'll fix this error.

Comment: The eqneditor for ckeditor  is being initiated once in overall application rest its showing black, teh script you shared is reading being called on each click of the icon however it is not initialising   equation